# jQuery Image Replacement

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace some main images with images from a gallery. Everything is working other than the replacement html img does not seem to be loading. For some reason the data is not loading. Any ideas? Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
 $(".thumbs li a").each(function() {
 var $thumb = $(this);
 $thumb.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var image_container = $thumb.parent().parent().parent().find('.image');
  var loading = $thumb.parent().parent().parent().find('.loading');

  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
      image_container.css('display', 'none');
      loading.css('display', 'inline-block');
    },
    url: 'image.php',
    data: ({src : $(this).attr('href')}),
    dataType: 'html',
    complete: function(data) {
      loading.css('display', 'none');
      image_container.css('display', 'inline-block');
      image_container.html(data);
      $thumb.parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      $thumb.parent().addClass('active');
    }
   });
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Got an example of what'll come back from image.php?

Comment: I'm not sure how the php is returned, but here is the code: <img src="<?php echo $_GET['src']; ?>"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**success** event instead of **complete**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Because first parameter of complete() is jqXHR object, not the response.

Comment: I can't get any response when using success.

Comment: And what do you get with **complete**?

Comment: With complete everything works other than this line:    
image_container.html(data);

Comment: It seems like the data is not loading

Comment: Try opening requested URL in your browser if you see any output. Maybe there's a problem with your server-side script

Comment: I got this to work by setting a jquery variable for the url path like this:       var $path = $(this).prop('href');